# sketch pdf of uniform random variable

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Considering the uniform random variable $f(a) = x.rect(a/y)$, how will be sketch of $f(a)$? And determine $x$.

Now, I have tried the problem but I could not even understand what does

"$x.rect(a/y)$" mean so that I could start the problem to solve.

Comment: How $x,y$ and $a$ are specified ?

Comment: "rect" stands for rectangle function,  sometimes written $\Pi (a)$  which describes exactly what this pdf should look like.  Perhaps a more familiar  notation would be $f(a) = \begin {cases} x & -\frac {y}{2}\le a \le \frac {y}{2}\\0 & otherwise \end {cases}$  I suppose technically it goes through the points $(-\frac y2,\frac x2),(\frac y2,\frac x2)$ at the endpoints, but that subtlety is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Got your point. Now, how to find the the constant "x"? and if I sketch it, along X axis it will go from -y/2 to y/2. but for Y axis what will be the height?

Comment: Update: found the value of Y axis. it is equal to 1/[y/2-(-y/2)] which means 1/y.